# What do nodes Body Parser and cookie parser do? And should I use them?

Tags: node.js, parsing, cookies, express, body-parser

I have read all the documentation I can find, but I can not find a simple explanation of what these two middleware do.

What does the `body` in `body-parser` refer to? Why does the body need to be parsed?

Similarly for cookies. Am I correct that `cookie-parser` "parses" or beaks down the cookies that accompany a web user?

Lastly, I have read that `body-parser` is both unsafe and deprecated in Express4. Should I not use it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you may know, Node.js provides by default a very low level [HTTP module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html). That's why you need "frameworks" like Express and such - they let you easily handle common features of web servers in other platforms (like Java and PHP, for example).

##### `body-parser`

[`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser) will take the body of your request and parse it to whatever you want your server to receive in `POST`/`PUT` requests (JSON, URL encoded, text, raw).
The only problem with body-parser (the far I know) is that you can't handle multipart bodies (which are commonly uploads).

Since Express version 4.16+ `body-parser` is included as a built-in middleware function in Express, there is no need to install it.

##### `cookie-parser`

[`cookie-parser`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cookie-parser) will parse the `Cookie` header and handle cookie separation and encoding, maybe even decrypt it!

Since Express 4.x `cookie-parser` is a standalone middleware, and to use it you must install it first.

This all comes down to the fact that you *don't need* to use these features, and that's why Node is great.
You can simply ignore them and have your server less busy :)

Comment: Ignoring them (if you need the information) would rely on using built in node modules (such as `querystring`) correct?

Comment: If you need such features, then yes, you will need to parse stuff somehow. At the very internals, these middlewares do a lot of hard work parsing stuff.

Comment: `multipart/form-data` is not just for "huge files" it's for *any* files.

Comment: I would add an additional clarification on these two packages.  Since Express version 4.16+ `body-parser` is included as a built-in middleware function in Express, there is no need to install it.

On the other hand `cookie-parser` is a standalone middleware (since Express 4.x ), and to use it you must install it first.

Answer (score 8):

In Express 4, [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) and [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) were moved to separate modules. The body and cookie parsers that were deprecated were the ones that shipped with Express 3.

The body parser parses request bodies. Those could contain like json or url encoded form data. The form data will then appear in `req.body`.

The cookie parser parses cookies and puts the cookie information on `req` object in the middleware. It will also decrypt signed cookies provided you know the secret.

Comment: I see, thank you for this. So, they are acceptable to use still? (I.e. not deprecated?)

Comment: @Startec yes, if you are building a web app on express 4, i'd recommend using them.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link to the documentation.](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded) It explain very well how to use it, and since from express 4x is a build in middleware function and it does same work as body-parser, you might not need to install body-parser.